# Simple jquery slider not going all the way through slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a simple jquery slider on codepen, and for some reason at the last slide, it reverts to the last one and bugs out.

https://codepen.io/zadro/pen/VxVXQy

```
    if ( $(window).width()<= 700) {  

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

 $('.switch-mobile').removeClass('small-products-text product-item-texts zstarrating2 small-pic-wrapper grid-item large--one-quarter medium--one-half small--one-whole on-sale home-small-products grid-uniform featured-row grid-item large--one-quarter medium--one-half small--one-whole on-sale'); 


var slideCount = $('.tester ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('.tester ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('.tester ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

$('.tester').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('.tester ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

$('.tester ul li:last-child').prependTo('.tester ul');

function moveLeft() {
    $('.tester ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 300, function () {
        $('.tester ul li:last-child').prependTo('.tester ul');
        $('.tester ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('.tester ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 300, function () {
        $('.tester ul li:first-child').appendTo('.tester ul');
        $('.tester ul').css('left', '');
    });
};

$('.tester_prev').click(function () {
    moveLeft();
    return false;
});

$('.tester_next').click(function () {
    moveRight();
    return false;
});
```

});

}

Please scroll to the end of the slider in mobile view, and you can see what I mean, it won't go back to the first slide. You will be able to find the HTML in the link, for some reason SO won't allow me to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

After you appened the list element back to `'.target ul'`, the new appended list item will not return with $('.target ul li:first-child'). Use `.first()` to fetch first child and `.last()` to fetch last child. so your code will look like this:

```
function moveLeft() {
    $('.tester ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
    }, 300, function () {
        $('.tester ul li').last().prependTo('.tester ul');
        $('.tester ul').css('left', '');

    });
};

function moveRight() {
    $('.tester ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 300, function () {
         $('.tester ul li').first().appendTo('.tester ul'); 
        $('.tester ul').css('left', '');

    });
};
```

Comment: I see that it works, but how is .first() and .last() working in this situations? Is it just going to the first '.tester ul li' and same with the last?